# Phaser Game Framework - Sprite.y value changed in 2 update loops despite conditional

Tags: javascript, game-engine, phaser-framework

This is a simple test case from a game in phaser.js. The ball moves to top of screen, collides, bounces down and stops because of a conditional, I set the sprite's y value and velocity to stop it falling further.

However, in the next update loop, the y value increases again, and count increases to 2.

From console.log - as ball descends y is 437,442,445, then remains on 440. I don't understand how ball.y goes beyond 440 twice, this is the entire running code. Setting bounce to 0 in conditional has no effect. It's not that console.log in the browser is out of sync with phaser update, because the count variable reports the conditional is entered twice.

```
    var mainState = {
    preload: function() { 
        game.load.image('ball', 'assets/ball.png'); 
    },
    create: function() { 
        game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        game.world.enableBody = true; 
        ball = game.add.sprite(180, 440, 'ball'); 
        ball.body.bounce.setTo(1); 
        ball.body.allowGravity = false; 
        ball.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
        game.physics.arcade.moveToXY(ball, 160,10,350); ballstop = false;
        count = 0;
    },  
    update: function() {
        console.log("ball.y " +  ball.y);
        if (ball.y > 440) { 
        ball.body.bounce.setTo(0); 
        ball.body.velocity.x = 0;
        ball.body.velocity.y = 0;
        ball.y = 440; 
        count = count + 1;
        }
    },
};
var game = new Phaser.Game(360, 640);
game.state.add('main', mainState); 
game.state.start('main');
```

Comment: Here's it running 
https://phaserballtest.netlify.com/ 

.Look at the console in Chrome Dev Tools to see the problem

Comment: Just some random guesses: Are the game physics handled concurrently to or decoupled from mainState's `update()`? Is there an acceleration value that needs to be set to `0`?

Answer (score 0):

Try [reseting the body](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html#reset).

The relevant block would look something like this:

```
if (ball.y > 440) {
    ball.body.bounce.setTo(0);
    ball.body.reset(0, 0);
    //ball.body.velocity.x = 0;
    //ball.body.velocity.y = 0;
    ball.y = 440;
    count = count + 1;
}
```

I've also saved a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hx28k007/) with this change.